# Multidimensional array not returning all MySQLi rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

As you can tell from the image below I'm only getting one row back in the frontend. I should be getting more than one row returned. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

```
public function chatBoxMembers() {
        $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
        $wow = $this->db->get_where('messages', array('messageRecipientId' => $userid));
        foreach($wow->result() as $row) {
            $imUser = array();
            $imUser['friendId'] = $row->messageSentById;
            $imUser['messageBody'] = $row->messageBody;
            $imUser['readStatus'] = $row->readStatus;
            $imUser['activityStatus'] = $row->activityStatus;
            $imUsers[] = $imUser;
        } echo json_encode(array($imUser));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want: **echo json_encode(array($imUsers));**

$imUsers no $imUser ?